# lftp not able to resolve alias value defined in .lftprc file

Tags: lftp

I have defined aliases in the config file .lftprc as below-

```
alias ftp_server_X 99.999.999.999
```

From the command prompt when I run

```
lftp -e "open -u user,password 99.999.999.999"
```

it connects to the server.

But when I try to use the alias name in the command

```
lftp -e "open -u user,password ftp_server_X"
```

I get error `'open: ftp_server_X: Name or service not known'`

Need help in resolving this error.

Answer (score 0):

lftp aliases are for commands, not for host names. Try bookmarks instead:

```
bookmark add ftp_server_X 99.99.99.99
```